# ManagedThreadId keeps increasing

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've noticed that in many of my services (which use multiple threads) the thread IDs keep increasing their values. Is this a sign of trouble? Am I somehow not returning them to the pool or is this value increase normal behavior?

Comment: Are they ThreadPool threads? If not, this sounds pretty normal.

Comment: Pretty odd that you'd think that them going down or staying equal is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your threads are returning (and not blocking, waiting, sleeping or in an infinite loop) then you're okay. ManagedThreadId is just a unique identifier, it isn't a "thread count" at all ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx )

> Thread.ManagedThreadId
>
> An integer that represents a unique identifier for this managed thread.

To be sure your threads are returning, pause your process in the VS debugger and tell it to freeze all threads and have a look at the Threads debug window. In a runtime environment I'd modify the thread code to increment a locked integer and to decrement the same locked integer when the thread returns (use a try/finally block to ensure a thrown exception doesn't cause the integer decrement to be missed).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @David. It all seems to be running OK, but I just notice after a couple of days the id value going over hundreds.

Comment: Also don't forget that the CLR runs its own threads, such as the GC and other threads necessary for COM support (even if you don't use COM).

Answer (score 2):

The 'correct' answer is no it is not normal. Not like CLR is broken. Your app should (most of the time unless you have some very good reason, of which I can't even imagine what it might be) use Thread threads carefully. If you are creating other the 100 threads you are 99% doing something wrong.

You either kill threads where you should re-use them OR you should use thread pool threads where you are using Thread threads.

**EDIT** OK. You might not trust me. But MSDN says the same:

> The value of the ManagedThreadId property does not vary over time, even if unmanaged code that hosts the common language runtime implements the thread as a fiber.

So just to stress it again (which I haven't made clear in first attempt)... You are not seeing thread Ids changing in the existing threads. You see different threads popping up (in hundreds by your own words).... New thread gets new ID. **Old thread does not change its ID.**

Comment: It is not the number of threads, rather the thread IDs that keep increasing their integer value.

Comment: my premise is that ID increases when you create a new thread by th = new Thread(); (or your thread pool is exhausted and it is creating new threads)... my premise is that once thread is created it wont change its ID. i would love to see a code which could prove me wrong.

Comment: I know, they are new threads. It just seemed odd that lower numbers would not be reused.

Comment: have i answered your question?

Comment: Close. I still don't quite understand if the thread IDs of newly created threads being always increasing is normal behavior (no threads are left unfinished).